# Порядок вызова ф

Tags: c++

Друзья, подскажите, какая последовательность выполнения кода, что вызыватся, куда копируется и тд.
немного попробую конкретизировать:
почему в выводе кроме hello другие символы?
как произошло копирование при *b=*a?(на сколько я понимаю, в объект Б, а точнее в его начало, где находился А, скопировались данные из участка памяти где хранился объект А) при этом не совсем понятно, что произошло с таблицей виртуальных функций объекта Б, да и вообще, как изменились таблицы виртуальных функций)

```
   class A {
   public:
    char*data;

   A(const char* msg = 0): data(new char[msg ? strlen(msg):0 +1]) 
    {
      if(msg)
      {
          memcpy(data,msg,strlen(msg));
      }
    }

   ~A() 
    {
       delete data;
    }

    virtual void say() 
      {
        std::cout << "A::say" << data << std::endl;
      }
    };

    class B: public A {
    public:
    int*data;
    B():A(),data(new int(0)) {}

    ~B() 
    {
      delete data;
    }

    virtual void say() 
    {
        std::cout << "B::say:" << *data <<std::endl;
    }
    };
    int main (){
    A *a = new A("hello");
    A *b = new B();
    a->say();
    *b=*a;
    b->say();
    }

    вывод
    A::sayhello¤¤¤¤лллллллл■ю■ю■ю■
    B::say:0
```

Comment: Что мешает взять отладчик и сделать это самому?

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите что-нибудь в таком духе? (Поскольку здесь нет вопроса про ошибки и почему так .)

1) Конструктор А `(msg = "hello")`. Где `data = "¤¤¤¤лллллллл■ю■ю■ю■"`
2) `memcpy:` `data = "hello¤¤¤¤лллллллл■ю■ю■ю■"`.
3) Вызывается конструктор Б `(data = undefined)`.
4) Обратно к конструктору А `(msg = NULL)` . `data = <Error reading characters of string.>`
5) Конструктор Б. `data  = (???)` -> `data = (int) 0`
6) `a->say();` -> функция `say()` в классе А.
7) `*a = "hello¤¤¤¤лллллллл■ю■ю■ю■"`
8) `*b = {0}`
9) `b->say();` -> функция `say()` в классе Б
10) Наконец `system("pause");`

Comment: 1) data проинициализировалось указателем на кусок памяти начиная с выделенного массива в 6 байт + ???  (пока 0 не встретился??)

Comment: 1) data проинициализировалась указателем на кусок памяти начиная с выделенного массива в 6 байт + ???....
4) как и в 1) - <Error reading characters of string.>перед методом memcpy, только тут он не срабатывает, в итоге имеем по указателю строку из не читаемых символов - ?, длины - ?.....

как именно произошло присваивание *b=*a, что происходило при вызове операторов= и в какой последовательности?